# Installing Winconn

Tags: remote-desktop, rdp

Let me start off by saying I'm a fairly new linux user and am somewhat competent in it's use but very competent in Windows. I just installed Ubuntu on my wife's computer which she uses to work from home. Her work uses Windows Remote App for some of her applications. I've tried installing Winconn for doing this but I'm running into some problems. If anyone has a better app suggestion I'm all ears however it needs to be accessible via GUI as she is coming from Windows. When trying to install Winconn I get the following error:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:realender/winconn
[sudo] password for briana:            
 WinConn RemoteApp connection manager
 More info: https://launchpad.net/~realender/+archive/ubuntu/winconn
Press [ENTER] to continue or Ctrl-c to cancel adding it.

Err:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/realender/winconn/ubuntu focal Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.52 80]
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/realender/winconn/ubuntu focal Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
briana@Briana-M900:~$ sudo apt-get update
Err:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/realender/winconn/ubuntu focal Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.52 80]
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/realender/winconn/ubuntu focal Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
briana@Briana-M900:~$ sudo apt-get install winconn
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package winconn
```

Forgive me for not formatting this correctly. This is my first time posting to this forum.

Comment: PPA's are 3rd party repositories, thus all security checks are your responsibility to perform. I took https://launchpad.net/~realender/+archive/ubuntu/winconn from your provided details & can quickly see that it supported two releases from ~2012; yet you appear to be using a 2020-April release (*focal*), thus adding it was a mistake as it can provide nothing *safe* or *useful* for your system. Check PPAs before adding them to your system (*especially if you value security*)

Comment: I absolutely value security. If anyone can suggest a better way of doing this I'm very much open to it. Currently she goes to her work domain via a browser, logs in and clicks the application she needs to use. That triggers an RDP shortcut to be downloaded which she opens and the application runs seamlessly as if it were on her computer. She still has her laptop right now that runs Windows but I'd like to make this work if possible.